# Making Authenticated Web Service Callouts Using One-Way SSL

Tags: callout, webservices, appexchange, ssl

How do I make web service call out using one-way ssl. I couldn't find any documentation on this. Salesforce has given documentation for two-way ssl connection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://krishhari.wordpress.com/2012/02/08/making-authenticated-web-service-callouts-from-salesforce-to-ibm-cast-iron-part-iii/

If the server is updated with one way SSL just use https and update your remote access settings .No further configuration is needed .

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Making_Authenticated_Web_Service_Callouts_Using_Two-Way_SSL

Tutorial 2 in the above document explains one way SSL.

Comment: SO it looks like the verification happens behind the scenes Salesofrce uses the chain of intermediate authorities to trace it to the one it's aware of. No import of the other server is needed because he is trusted based on some of the CA that sign his cert. right?